# External audio device goes to sleep if no audio is sent from Windows every few seconds

Tags: audio, windows-11, sleep, headphone-jack, external

I have an external Bluetooth audio device (UE Boom) that I have connected to my Windows 11 PC through the auxiliary headphone jack (NOT BLUETOOTH). As long as the PC is sending continous audio to the speaker, all is good. But if I am working on something that only makes a sound when I trigger it, is goes to sleep. It does wake up, but some of the initial audio is lost.

As an example, if I am on an audio conference call, as long as others speak, the speaker stays on, but when they stop and I talk (even for a few seconds), and others start speaking again, a few seconds of their conversation is lost until the device wakes up.

In order to circumvent this, I play a very long YouTube video at close to zero volume. This works fine, but is not ideal by any means. Specially during video calls (screen sharing).

Is there a way that I can have Windows keep the device on forcefully? Any advise or alternate suggestions would be appreciated.